# Why does Ubuntu 13.04 fails to start showing a purple screen and on restart shows a blank(black) screen with blinking cursor?

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, dual-boot

I've installed `Ubuntu 13.04` from my USB and straight away I got problems. I've `Windows 7` installed in my PC. Therefore I've chosen ubuntu installation along side Windows 7. The problem I'm facing is that Ubuntu fails to start after installation. I've reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 many times. But the problem seems to be there. The very first run after installation seems to be working fine. But on a next restart, the issue will pop up. The startup screen is showing that I've got `Ubuntu` and `Windows 7` installed in my PC. Windows is working fine. But upon selecting Ubuntu its showing a purple screen and I was forced to restart the PC using the restart button. Upon restart, again the startup screen shows up.(Please note that the auto login countdown is not shown at this time). Two OS installed in the PC is listed down and this time the scenario is little bit different. Now, selecting Ubuntu will produce a black screen with blinking cursor. Why is this happening? I don't know what is the real issue behind this. I lurked around various sites but couldn't find a solution. I don't know whether my hardware has got any relation with this issue. Please help me. I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and I'm really frustrated with this issue.

The configuration of my PC is ,

```
Intel i5 processor 2500K,
Intel H67 Motherboard,
4GB RAM,
nvidia GT520 graphics card,
and a 500GB HDD
```

Comment: @guntbert Thanks for posting a useful link. But it doesn't contain the solution to the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: Which answers did you try? How did they fail?